# Using node-red in Bluemix,I get this error: The Workspace contains unknown node types

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am using node-red in Bluemix cloud and I am getting this error starting today. It worked last time and I am not able figure out why. I re-created the nodes but got the same error. The error prompts to Twitter.in node. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Please provide the details of the error and also what your application was doing when you received the error, so that we can help you determine what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error you are getting it is difficult to tell what is causing it, but I suspect that you are being prompted for a twitter id, and permissions to view / post to a timeline. You probably saw this initially and set it, and forgot about it. Subsequently the original permission / token has expired you are being prompted to reissue the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a period "." in the twitter in node definition?  It should instead be  "type":"twitter in"  with a space and no period.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It does not have a period. It was taken from Node-red library. Now there is an error saying, "The workspace contains some unused configuration nodes:   (twitter-credentials)    Are you sure you want to deploy?". But it gives the output correctly now. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Is it possible you have an extra node that is not linked to the flow?